# Can you import a file with each line as array and compare it with a variable in php?

Tags: php, html, function

I've got a website running and to go to a different page I'd like to import a list with all different page names (each one in its own line) so I can compare each row with the given page value.

First I look which page it is (index.php):

```
$get_page = '';
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $get_page = $_GET['page'];
}
else{
    $get_page = 'home';
}
setPage($get_page);
```

Then I import my 'pages.txt' and set the page (This works in a function) I included before (functions.php):

```
function setPage($page){
    $all_pages = file('pages.txt');
    foreach ($all_pages as $line_num) {
        if($line_num == $page){
        echo $line_num;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this won't help me to set the page but I that's not the problem.

pages.txt looks like following:

```
borrowed
edit
home
new
```

since I start on my index.php with nothing set $get_page should be home. I tested it and it is. I also echoed out all $line_num's. It works, too. $get_page is 'home' and one entry in pages.txt is 'home'. But if I compare them as shown it doesn't echo 'home' as it should.

Comment: RTFM: [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) `Note: Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.`

Comment: Seems like this is the problem with 90% of people having trouble with `file()`.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcB I totally forgot these special chars! It works now ;)